# OC4J Aspose License file load

Tags: java, oc4j, aspose.words

```
import com.aspose.words.License;

public void loadLicense() throws LicenseNotFoundException {
    File licenseFile = new File("c:\Aspose.Total.Java.lic");
    if (licenseFile.exists()) {
        try {
            License license = new License();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(licenseFile);
            license.setLicense(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new LicenseNotFoundException(licenseFile.getAbsolutePath() + " not loaded. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        throw new LicenseNotFoundException(licenseFile.getAbsolutePath() + " cannot be found.");
    }
}
```

Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: !META-INF/MANIFEST.MF not found in file:c/oc4j_101350/j2ee/home/applications/xxx/lib/Aspose.Words.jdk14.jar
>
> !META-INF/MANIFEST.MF not found in file:C/oc4j_101350/j2ee/home/applications/xx/lib/Aspose.Words.jdk14.jar

Configuration:

1. JDK 1.5.06
2. OC4J Standalone 10.1.3
3. Aspose.Words.jdk14.jar

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using quite old version of Aspose.Words for Java. Please download and try latest version of [Aspose.Words for Java](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/java). It will resolve the issue.

I'm Tilal, developer evangelist at Aspose.